# loading dynamic html into dompdf using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic-data, dompdf

hello i'm working on a script which will dynamically load html using `file_get_contents` and will generate and save the pdf on the server but somehow my php file is giving me **500 internal server error** so is there any other way to load the html into dompdf
here is my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require("includes/check_auth_user.php");
require("includes/dbconnect.php");
include ('includes/function.php');
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$mvouch = $_REQUEST["vouchno"];
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$html =file_get_contents("http://www.myurl.com/project/file_to_be_loaded.php?vouchno=$mvouch");
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("/files/report.pdf", $output);
echo "<h1>DONE!!!</h1>";
?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to wkhtmltopdf? I find that it's a better library & tool to create PDFs from HTML. if you want to troubleshoot the 500 error, you need to have a look at the php error_log files (linux: /var/log/apache2/error_log or /var/log/nginx/error_log) to see what the processor is throwing as the message.

Comment: Also, you have a space between include & ( `include ('includes...');`

Comment: it is showing me this error `Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /home/cepheisys/public_html/sbsweb/include/dompdf.cls.php on line 629`

Comment: It means you don't have libxml installed and the XML php library. On the phone so can't link but Google 'php install xml'

Comment: As Justin says, you're missing DOMDocument, a core PHP extension. It's enabled by default, but some hosting providers explicitly disable it. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it!

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require('includes/check_auth_user.php');
require('includes/dbconnect.php');
include ('includes/function.php');
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

require_once('file_to_be_loaded.php?vouchno='.$mvouch');

$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('/files/report.pdf', $output);
echo '<h1>DONE!!!</h1>';
?>
```

Perhaps you want to have a dynamic filename on the reportfile aswell and sort folders by year/MONTH

```
$month  = date('Ym');
$date= Date("Y-m-d");
$time = Date("His");
$filename = 'files/'.$month.'/report'.$date.'_'.$time.'.pdf';
        if (!is_dir("files/".$month)) {
          // dir doesn't exist, make it
          mkdir("files/".$month);
}
file_put_contents($filename, $output);
```

**file_to_be_loaded.php** - should look something like this

```
$html = '
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <html lang="sv">
</head>
<body>';
$html .='<h2>Report</h2>';
$html .='
</body>
</html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use centos as the server, this is the solution to `Fatal error: Class 'DOMDocument' not found in /var/www/html/include/dompdf.cls.php on line 177`:

To install PHP-XML run the following command: yum install php-xml

To install DOM/XML run the following command: yum whatprovides php-dom

To restart Apache run the following command: service httpd restart